# How to set high, low and medium priority email using queue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am studying **[Job dispatching from here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#introduction)**

**Problem**

I read that each connection has queue parameter which tell the queue name. Question is: How can I set the priority to send low or medium or high priority email?

**Cmd prompt**

I am using command: **php artisan queue:listen** to process job.

**What I tried?**

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default
```

but this code never works if connection's queue parameter has value is not high

**Default Queue Driver**

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

**Queue Connections**

```
'connections' => [

    'Register' => [
        'driver'        =>  'database',
        'table'         =>  'tbljobs',
        'queue'         =>  'low',
        'retry_after'   =>  5,
    ],

    'ForgotPassword' => [
        'driver'        =>  'database',
        'table'         =>  'tbljobs',
        'queue'         =>  'low',
        'retry_after'   =>  5,
    ],

],
```

**.env**

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=Register
```

**Controller Code for Register email**

```
$job = (new SendActivationEmail($Data))
        ->onConnection('Register');
dispatch($job);
```

**Controller Code for Reset Password**

```
$job = (new SendResetPasswordEmail($this->tokens->create($user), $user))
        ->onConnection('ForgotPassword');
dispatch($job);
```

Comment: You are using $User variable in your job's handle method. Are you sure it's defined?

Comment: yes, I can confirm that User object has value and I verified it by printing the object in .env file.

Comment: Did you start your queue worker? `php artisan queue:work --queue=high`

Comment: In order to make this work...Is it necessary that in queue connection list...I must have a connection with a name of high?

Comment: Do you mean priority as a nice red arrow up in the Outlook, or processing the queues in a different peace?

Comment: php artisan queue:work --queue=high,low see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#queue-priorities

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take note of the **Connections Vs. Queues** note in [Laravel's queue documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues), which applies to all queue drivers apart from SQS as far as I'm aware.

> Before getting started with Laravel queues, it is important to
>   understand the distinction between "connections" and "queues". In your
>   config/queue.php configuration file, there is a connections
>   configuration option. This option defines a particular connection to a
>   backend service such as Amazon SQS, Beanstalk, or Redis. However, any
>   given queue connection may have multiple "queues" which may be thought
>   of as different stacks or piles of queued jobs.
>
> Note that each connection configuration example in the queue
>   configuration file contains a queue attribute. This is the default
>   queue that jobs will be dispatched to when they are sent to a given
>   connection. In other words, if you dispatch a job without explicitly
>   defining which queue it should be dispatched to, the job will be
>   placed on the queue that is defined in the queue attribute of the
>   connection configuration:

In effect you will register one queue connection in your `config/queues.php` file and the `default` parameter will simply be the queue that jobs are dispatched to by default, if another queue is not provided.

Vitaly's answer above would be the correct approach to the problem (consolidate to a single connection with a default queue) then adjust your jobs to get sent to different queues if required. This is some important (I think) context to how how queue configuration works.

Answer (score 16):

```
'connections' => [

    'Register' => [ //<this name is connection name
        'driver'        =>  'database',
        'table'         =>  'tbljobs',
        'queue'         =>  'low',  //<this name is default queue name then you register a queue using this connection
        'retry_after'   =>  5,
    ],
],
```

I suggest you modify your code in the following way:

```
'connections' => [
    'Register' => [
        'driver'        =>  'database',
        'table'         =>  'tbljobs',
        'queue'         =>  'default',
        'retry_after'   =>  5,
    ],
],
```

**High priority job - Controller Code for Register email**

```
$job = (new SendActivationEmail($Data))
        ->onConnection('Register')
        ->onQueue("high");
dispatch($job);
```

**Medium priority job - Controller Code for Reset Password**

```
$job = (new SendResetPasswordEmail($this->tokens->create($user), $user))
        ->onConnection('Register')
        ->onQueue("medium");
dispatch($job);
```

**Low priority job**

```
dispatch((new LowPriorityJob())->onQueue("low"));
```

**Default priority job**

```
dispatch((new DefaultPriorityJob()));
```

> ->onConnection('Register') //this line is usefull if you specify you default connection is Register in .env QUEUE_DRIVER=Register

**Run your jobs**

this command run your jobs stored in default connection. In your case Register

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=high,medium,low,default
```

this command run your jobs stored in customConnectionName connection

```
php artisan queue:work customConnectionName --queue=high,medium,low,default
```

Comment: default means queue name. This is not setting any priority.

Comment: @Pankaj,, `default` means `default` queue based on `config/queue.php` file...

Answer (score 7):

You should have two queues defined in your `config/queue.php` file. Say, one with the name "high" and the other "low".

Then, you can then dispatch jobs to them as needed like this:

```
$job = (new SendResetPasswordEmail($this->tokens->create($user), $user))
        ->onConnection('ForgotPassword');
dispatch($job)->onQueue('high'));
```

**Note: `->onQueue('high')`**

Finally, you would run:
`php artisan queue:work --queue=high,low`

This will start a worker that will process all jobs on "high" queue before moving on to jobs on "low".

Comment: high : means queue name. This is not setting any kind of priority.

Comment: @Helper yes, it's the queue name, but the order in which you put the queue names is the order in which they will be grabbed from, so you get priority through that

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
'connections' => [

'Register-low' => [
    'driver'        =>  'database',
    'table'         =>  'tbljobs',
    'queue'         =>  'low',
    'retry_after'   =>  5,
],
'Register-high' => [
    'driver'        =>  'database',
    'table'         =>  'tbljobs',
    'queue'         =>  'high',
    'retry_after'   =>  5,
],

'ForgotPassword' => [
    'driver'        =>  'database',
    'table'         =>  'tbljobs',
    'queue'         =>  'low',
    'retry_after'   =>  5,
],

],
```

AND then

php artisan queue:listen --queue=Register-high,Register-low

Comment: `Register-high` is connection Name and `high` is queue name. Where is priority?

Comment: @Pankaj the priority comes from the order how you write the command --queue=HigherPriority,LoweverPriority,LowerThanLowerPriority,...

Answer (score 1):

Queue priorities is explained here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#queue-priorities.
You simply need to "pass a comma-delimited list of queue names to the work command."

As the documentation says:

`php artisan queue:work --queue=high,low`

So `dispatch((new Job)->onQueue('high'))` will be given higher priority than `dispatch((new Job)->onQueue('low'))`.

Or you could use your custom queue names:

`php artisan queue:work --queue=first,second`.